# Copying to Android System Folder programmatically

Tags: android

I'm implementing a new feature on Android 10(10.0.0_r30) that has to copy files from the data folder to the system folder at runtime. I've tried to do it via 'su cp' in Zygote, since Zygote runs as root, but then I get this error:

`type=1400 audit(0.0:61): avc: denied { getattr } for name="su" dev="dm-0" ino=3160 scontext=u:r:zygote:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:su_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=1`

SELinux is disabled and I have no clue where else to look for the resolution of this error. Also, the system folder is writeable(parameter given to the emulator)

Besides that, can anyone tell me how else I could implement this particular task without rooting?

Comment: I don't understand a think: do you want to change Android behaviour by changing its source code and then build a new AOSP/release? Because I'm not understand how you would run "su cp" command "without rooting"....

Comment: Exactly, I want to change AOSP so that some process can successfully execute "su cp" on a file from the data folder and copy it to the system folder, preferrably without rooting